# Multiple Rows Column to SIngle Column if same user_id

Tags: mysql, go

I am working on a function which gets user with products list. My problem is that I have to return the result of many queries as one result in the rows.Next(). One user can have more than 1 product with a query to relate the user and product tables

```
SELECT users.id as user_id, users.name, products.name as product_name, products.id as product_id  
JOIN user_products ON users.id = user_products.user_id
JOIN products ON products.id = user_products.product_id
```

and get the results

| user_id | name | product_name | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack | Ice Taro Latte | 2 |
| 1 | Jack | Avocado Juice | 5 |
| 3 | Michael | Orange Juice | 8 |
| 7 | Angel | Avocado Juice | 5 |

The expectation is that if the user id is the same it will be grouped and will create a slice inside the UserProduct struct like this

```
type Products struct {
        ProductID   int     `json:"product_id"`
        ProductName string  `json:"product_name"`
    }
type UserProduct struct {
        UserID      int         `json:"user_id"`
        UserName    string      `json:"user_name"`
        Products    []Products  `json:"product"`
    }
```

but now it is still displayed as in the SQL table above, how about how to group data into grouped by user_id?

here is my code

```golang
type Products struct {
        ProductID   int     `json:"product_id"`
        ProductName string  `json:"product_name"`
    }
type UserProduct struct {
        UserID      int         `json:"user_id"`
        UserName    string      `json:"user_name"`
        Products    []Products  `json:"product"`
    }

func GetUserProducts() ([]UserProduct, error) {
    var userProducts []UserProduct

    query := `SELECT users.id as user_id, users.name, products.name as product_name, products.id as product_id  
    JOIN user_products ON users.id = user_products.user_id
    JOIN products ON products.id = user_products.product_id`

    //use "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    rows, err := db.QueryxContext(ctx, query)

    for rows.Next() {
        var userProduct UserProduct

        err := rows.StructScan(&userProduct)

        if err != nil {
            log.Err(err).Msg(err.Error())
            continue
        }

        userProducts = append(userProducts, userProduct)

    }


    return labels, nil
}
```

Expected(IN JSON)

```
{
    "user_product": [
        {
            "user_id": 1,
            "user_name": "Jack",
            "product": [
                {
                    "product_id": 2,
                    "product_name": "ice taro latte"
                },
                {
                    "product_id": 5,
                    "product_name": "ovocado juice"
                },
                {
                    "product_id": 5,
                    "product_name": "ovocado juice"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "user_id": 3,
            "user_name": "Michael",
            "product": [
                {
                    "product_id": 8,
                    "product_name": "Orange Juice"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "user_id": 7,
            "user_name": "Angel",
            "product": [
                {
                    "product_id": 5,
                    "product_name": "Avocado Juice"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks for advance

Comment: *"My problem is that I have to return the result of many queries as one result in the rows.Next()."* -- What is it that stops you from executing two queries separately and aggregating the results from the two separate `rows` instances? What kind of requirement forces you to have only one `rows`?

Comment: What I mean here is to return only 1 row with a slice/array in it (see JSON to see the expected result), so 1 user id can have many products @mkopriva

Comment: I think the best way to do this is to transform and group the data in the `rows.Next()` loop. Since you want to keep the info about the products (you can not use SQL GROUP BY) so either ORDER BY user_id column and just keep the id from previous row (so you know you have jumped to next user) or use map.
I do not think such grouping is in the scope of sqlx package, take a look at [GORM](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm) or [entgo](https://entgo.io) if you do not want to write your sql queries and do the transformation

Answer (score 0):

[Solved]

I made 1 more query to retrieve product data(queries that have been JOIN with users), then the product data is looped in rows.next() users (queries users without joining products). After that, if (users.id == products.users_id) is created, then append. the results of the append are mapped to the UserProducts struct

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).